# I would like to connect my Kinect v2 to my pc in ubuntu 22.04, Is it possible?

Tags: drivers, 22.04, opencv, kinect

I am trying to use the Kinect v2 for a project using OpenCV in Ubuntu, but a quick Google search gives me the drivers for Ubuntu 20.04 only. I Don't know how to proceed. Should the Ubuntu version be a problem or can it be used with 22.04? Currently, I am waiting for the power adapter, hence can't test this theory

Comment: Ask the people who provide the 20.04 drivers when they will build an up-to-date one.